# Is there a way to make Enter and Shift + Enter work the same way in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I'm using tinymce-react package in my current project. Is there a way to make "enter" and "shift + enter" work the same way? In my case I need them both to insert `<p></p>` when pressed. I tried different variations of `force_root_block`, `force_p_newlines` and `force_br_newlines` but it always ends up that one of them insert `<p></p>` and the other one `<br/>`. Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
//target textarea with querySelector
var textA = document.querySelector("textarea");
textA.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // keyCode 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  // keyCode 16 is the "Shift" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.keyCode === 16) {
    // Prevent default action
    event.preventDefault();
    //if shift or enter are pressed then insert new paragraph
    textA.value = textA.value + "<p></p>"
  }
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Well not entirely, I wanted it to insert new line with <p> tags instead of <br/> but I found the solution. I simply check if both enter and shift are pressed and I run `mceInsertNewLine` function and it works as intended.

Comment: I used `tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('InsertLineBreak');`. See [exposed editor commands](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/).